# can snakeyaml write back in original order?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I have a yaml file with the following content:

```
- examPart: A
  name: A1
  yxsj: 1
  yxzd: 2
  jypp: 3
 
- examPart: B
  name: B1
  yxsj: 2
  yxzd: 3
  jypp: 4
```

I have a java class with these fields defined there:

```
public class Template
{
    private String examPart;
    private String name; 
    private String yxsj; 
    private String yxzd; 
    private String jypp; 

    public Template()
    {
    }
```

When I read the yaml file, add a new `Template` to the data list, and write back to the yaml file, the field order changed like this:

```
- examPart: A
  jypp: 3
  name: A1
  yxsj: 1
  yxzd: 2

- examPart: B
  jypp: 4
  name: B1
  yxsj: 2
  yxzd: 3

- examPart: C
  jypp: 5
  name: C1
  yxsj: 3
  yxzd: 4
```

The field's order is changed. It looks like they are sorted. But I don't want the sorted order. I want to keep the original order or the order they are inside the `Template` class. How can I keep the custom field/variable order? I snakeyaml cannot do this, is there any other Java yaml implementation that can do this?

Comment: why does that order matter? because in the standard JSON/ YAML implementation only the order of the array has to be preserved, the order inside the object is not important.

Comment: if you really need to show it in order, then you can sort it before you print it... there is no point trying to sort it in memory, because most of the implementations don't care about the order...

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Sometimes the order does matter because these output files may be read by people then.

Comment: I was told that YAML is more readable than JSON, XML, and others. Based on the issue I am facing, I don't agree with that. In many cases, the order of the information is really important.

Comment: i agree, and that argument will start a whole war where none of the sides win, the reason that the sequences do not matter is that it will be implemented as a hashmap internally, and a hashmap, by design, shouldn't care about sequence, however, you will face the same issue with JSON, json also doesn't care about the sequence when you are inside the object

Comment: @SamridhTuladharI am not complaining about the YAML. I am complaining about the SNAKEYAML implementation. At least there should be a way to give users an easy method to enforce the result sequence/order and it is not hard to do, I think. For example, we can allow users to easily set/configure this by passing a file/string list or .... into its Representer class or ...

Comment: yeah, i know, but in the YAML specifications itself it says that you don't have to maintain the sequence... in other words, to pass the test as a YAML manipulation library, it's not necessary to maintain the sequence, sure, your library can have that feature, but it's just bonus points.